# Efeito paralaxe/parallax não funciona no Chrome para Android, mas funciona no desktop

Tags: html, android, css, google-chrome, parallax

Tenho esta página: http://einconformado.blogspot.com.br/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html onde utilizo o efeito paralaxe/parallax, e, sim, o efeito funciona tranquilamente no Chrome e no Firefox (versões desktop), mas **no Chrome para Android, o efeito não funciona, ficando "normal" sem o estilo parallax propriamente dito** (o paralaxe funciona, inclusive, no IE11 do Windows Phone, mas não pega no Chrome 65 móvel)

Quem se propor a verificar utilizando o Chrome, pode ver que no desktop flui, mas no Android, não. O que pode ser?

Não estou utilizando plugins para o efeito, apenas CSS puro.

```js
$(function () {
$('a[href="#compartilhar"]').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('.social_fix').addClass('open');
});

$("#main-wrapper").on("click", function(e) {var fechar = $(".social_fix.open").css('opacity'); if (fechar == 1) {$('.social_fix').removeClass("open");}});
$(document).keyup(function(event) {if (event.keyCode == 27) {$('.social_fix').removeClass('open');}});
});

function Copy() {urlCopied.innerHTML = window.location.href;}
function copyToClipboard(element) {var $temp = $("<input/>"); $("body").append($temp); $temp.val($(element).text()).select(); document.execCommand("copy"); $temp.remove(); alert("Link copiado para a área de transferência.");}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:319px) {.bgimg-1 {min-height: 260px!important} .um span.border {line-height:26px!important; font-size:30px!important; letter-spacing:2px!important} .um {top:2%!important} .escuro .border-dois {font-size:13px!important}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 320px) {.um span.border {padding:47px!important; font-size:50px!important; letter-spacing:-3px!important} .caption {top:15%!important; padding:27% 0} .border-dois, .border-tres, .border-quatro {padding:1px; font-size:32px; letter-spacing:4px; line-height:1.4em} .um {top:10%!important} .bgimg-1 {min-height:430px!important} .escuro .border-dois {font-size:13px!important}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {.um span.border {font-size:55px!important; letter-spacing:-1px!important; padding:55px!important}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {.um span.border {font-size:70px!important; letter-spacing:-4px!important; line-height:1.1em!important}}
@media only screen and (max-width: 3000px) and (min-width: 980px) {.um span.border {letter-spacing:-4px!important; line-height:1.1em!important} .um {padding:5% 0} .border-dois, .border-tres, .border-quatro {font-size:80px; letter-spacing:4px; line-height:1em} .css-text-mask {font-size:80px!important}}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {background-attachment:scroll}}

h3 {letter-spacing:5px; text-transform:uppercase; font:20px "Lato", sans-serif; color:#D80000; text-align:center}
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {position:relative; opacity:0.65; background-attachment:fixed; background-position:center; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover}
.bgimg-1 {background-image:url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/t9mRHg_UqWfOLsZ1RzYzX48k1z1H68-qT_12SU0ZPUMyprqFrybFtTLzFTMI6DL2YSObnoerAbBaCdhPufZgXQZPRZ9AD-Q04Z302Y8zA96c58yX-u0VqnRXsNTuFyife_g7-kNsbw=w1075-h666-no"); min-height:520px}
.bgimg-2 {background-image:url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/T26XJTBwbHQTrj-KzXsAVw5s5n-Ckbcq-rEKRJsYSgnZ4O5yJEN_sC5RBKUeshtnK1-mYIIjOphuzGuAPtpvrxzeE5Y9_Un31u33gcWzXNBpjtBnDHTKcDKJiP9vEofFZ4CRBZYxQA=w1011-h666-no"); min-height:400px}
.bgimg-3 {background-image:url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZRH2HqG_Jq0/VkzgpCeNtoI/AAAAAAAAEKU/h5FvYT7NwUU/s800-Ic42/inkinwater11.jpg"); min-height:400px}
.border-dois, .border-tres, .border-quatro {padding:10px; background-color:#D80000; font-size:25px; color:#f7f7f7; cursor:pointer}
.border-dois:hover, .border-tres:hover, .border-quatro:hover {background-color:#A80000}
.boxtextop {color:#ddd; background-color:#282E34; text-align:center; padding:40px; text-align:justify; position:relative; box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.45)}
.caption {position:absolute; left:0; top:50%; width:100%; text-align:center; color:#000}
.caption a {color:#fff!important; position:relative; text-transform:uppercase}
.caption a:before {content:""; position:absolute; width:100%; height:2px; bottom:0; left:0; background-color:#fff; visibility:hidden; transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; transform:scaleX(0)}
.caption a:hover:before {visibility:visible; transform:scaleX(1)}
.css-text-mask {text-align:center; font-size:50px; color:#000; background-clip:text!important; -webkit-background-clip:text!important; background:url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/y9MKda9i5hObwu7SqD5NsJ_s6ny0c8VsR1U9iAqlTtG89vYkkfEszcsMpwYUQz3MkTFtSwXbGtB0ZWLQPIH7bV53rXwFOfAeIeNMdBmuu61QYNLY1svefhpG2x_iQvEdgCjf1CSZdnWx9EVJr0YbGfxDMg346wxk0MRfoNSgZlQdlwNeNHCah_la2GAsG_c_mEmMmwKTY9caUDC4hSXGwTuvdmGvsAKBuU7lHp9_04Hq_komqmEM83M1exK1BvZsdxyCPZRZEEOuSDSR_28e4t3WQfqkjXBflZ0OSX_oz2rztnr4T8aYtqO_6KxGFH5NOxFrSqb2sd4YLO5hgN_PV3US03-8txEJIi1iXdRXG3_y4YPpok1nTCJzxUGoaIcXv4dszQ3GdM055lIKkgSNRm6FXe5JgyllEw5shP3jCH9Q9k93P9YKnVOMjbcNSQ4433VFVgNOt9qQTwYX1KiPijPInB0mv87YygB0HYUc5woZk4hO8es2rBqgJ5zwiYXYPs3rPrsrsvbKJlIPCi3FZN7KH6lEw8_53-59ULG1AccZegXQnB6LbCkHMdi2KqtqJ_UXALS1JqcaO3bFUEGaho-37EGUvG4Yem7DzgGag1OblouOrEXhd7vv69mrWNneYggRkdeRfr-oMALVxiWxH1Sh_zJDq1Pp=w700-h490-no) 0 0 / 25%; -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent; text-fill-color:transparent; line-height:50px; font-family:Oswald; font-weight:bold; text-transform:uppercase}
.escuro h3 {color:#ff0!important}
.escuro .bgimg-1, .escuro .bgimg-2, .escuro .bgimg-3 {opacity:1!important}
.escuro .border-dois, .escuro .border-tres, .escuro .border-quatro {background-color:#000!important; border:3px solid #ff0}
.escuro .border-dois:hover, .escuro .border-tres:hover, .escuro .border-quatro:hover {background-color:#000!important; border:3px solid #1aebff}
.escuro .boxtextop {background-color:#000!important}
.escuro .css-text-mask {filter:brightness(10%)!important}
.post-body {padding:0!important}
.um {top:25%; text-align:center; position:absolute; left:0; width:100%}
.um span.border {background-color:#111; color:#fff; padding:18px; font-size:25px; letter-spacing:10px}

ul.social_menu {font-size:200%; text-align:center}
ul.social_menu li a {height:33px; position:relative; text-decoration:none; color:#fff!important}
ul.social_menu li a:before, ul.social_menu li a:hover:before {display:none!important}
ul.social_menu li::before {font-family:fontawesome; color:#fff; font-size:85%}
.social_fix {padding:0 0 0 5px; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:15%; height:100%; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.99); opacity:0; z-index:999999; transform:translate(-100%, 0%); box-shadow:7px -3px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.9); transition:all 0.5s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1); overflow:auto}
.social_fix.open {transform:translate(0, 0) scale(1, 1); opacity:1}
.social_txt span {font-size:85%; font-family:Open Sans; padding:0 18px; color:#fff}
.texto_compartilhe {font-family:Oswald; font-size:3em; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; color:#fff; padding:0 9px; line-height:100%}
#social_menu_animation:hover li {opacity:0.2}
#social_menu_animation li {-webkit-transition-property:opacity; -moz-transition-property:opacity}
#social_menu_animation li:hover {opacity:1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='social_fix'>
<p class='texto_compartilhe'>Envie nosso livro para alguém!</p>
<div class='social_txt'>
<ul class='social_menu' id='social_menu_animation' style='padding:0!important'>
<li class='fa fa-facebook'><a href='https://www.facebook.com/share.php?v=4&+++src=bm&+++u=http://einconformado.blogspot.com/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html+++&+++t=Conheça%20o%20(primeiro)%20livro%20do%20Eterno%20Inconformado:&ext=1521256863&hash=Aea-I82uDdeTUmtX' onclick='window.open(this.href,&quot;   sharer&quot;   ,&quot;   toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436&quot;   );   return false;   ' rel='nofollow' title='Espalhe no Facebook'><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
<li class='fa fa-twitter'><a href='http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Conheça%20o%20(primeiro)%20livro%20do%20Eterno%20Inconformado:%20http://einconformado.blogspot.com/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Espalhe no Twitter'><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
<li class='fa fa-whatsapp' id='whats-celular'><a data-action='share/whatsapp/share' href='whatsapp://send?text=Conheça%20o%20(primeiro)%20livro%20do%20Eterno%20Inconformado:%20http://einconformado.blogspot.com/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html' rel='nofollow' title='Espalhe no WhatsApp'><span>WhatsApp</span></a></li>
<li class='fa fa-whatsapp' id='whats-pc'><a data-action='share/whatsapp/share' href='https://web.whatsapp.com/send?text=Conheça%20o%20(primeiro)%20livro%20do%20Eterno%20Inconformado:%20http://einconformado.blogspot.com/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html' rel='nofollow' target='_blank' title='Espalhe no WhatsApp'><span>WhatsApp</span></a></li>
<li class='fa fa-google-plus'><a href='https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?url=http://einconformado.blogspot.com/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html' onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,&quot;   &quot;   ,&quot;   menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600&quot;   );   return false;   ' rel='nofollow' title='Espalhe no Google+'><span>Google+</span></a></li>
<li class='fa fa-envelope'><a href='mailto:?subject=Conheça%20o%20(primeiro)%20livro%20do%20Eterno%20Inconformado%21 &amp;body=http://einconformado.blogspot.com/p/livraria-do-eterno-inconformado.html' rel='nofollow' title='Espalhe por e-mail'><span>E-mail</span></a></li>
<li class='fa fa-clone'><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="Copy(); copyToClipboard('#urlCopied');" title='Copie a URL do nosso livro para enviá-la a alguém'><span>Copiar URL</span></a><textarea id="urlCopied" style="display:none" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea></li>
</ul>
</div></div>

<div class='bgimg-1'>
 <div class='um'>
 <span class='border css-text-mask'>O (primeiro) Livro do Eterno Inconformado</span>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class='boxtextop'>
 <h3>A obra</h3>
 <p>O (primeiro) Livro do Eterno Inconformado é composto por 23 capítulos que abordam de maneira metafórica e prosaica o confronto que temos após revermos sob a ótica cristã o mundo e os desafios cotidianos.</p>
 <p>Além de reflexões pessoais (contextualizadas e embasadas biblicamente) a respeito de diversos temas, nosso primeiro livro é um compêndio de alguns dos textos publicados entre Junho de 2012 e Agosto de 2016 em nosso blog; textos esses reeditados para compor a obra e, além deles, o livro traz ainda vários textos inéditos compostos durante esse período.</p>
 <p>Nosso objetivo é glorificar a Deus e crer que Ele fale contigo, amado leitor, da maneira que Lhe for agradável. Cremos que - como a Palavra nos ensina em 1 Coríntios 14:3 – aquilo que Ele tem nos ensinado sirva para consolo, edificação e exortação (e, não, nosso livro não é autoajuda) de todo aquele que ler o (primeiro) livro do Eterno Inconformado.</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class='bgimg-2'>
 <div class='caption'>
 <span class='border-dois'><a href='https://www.behance.net/gallery/61953937/O-(primeiro)-Livro-do-Eterno-Inconformado-Ilustracoes' target='_blank' title='Aprecie 23 imagens instigantes em nosso (primeiro) livro!'>Imagens Instigantes!</a></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class='boxtextop'>
 <p>Em O (Primeiro) Livro do Eterno Inconformado, você também encontrará 23 imagens surrealistas e metafóricas que ilustram cada capítulo ao trazer de maneira implícita a mensagem abordada pelos textos e, certamente, a interpretação de cada uma delas irá variar de acordo com a percepção do leitor. Clique <a href='https://www.behance.net/gallery/61953937/O-(primeiro)-Livro-do-Eterno-Inconformado-Ilustracoes' target='_blank'>aqui</a> para conhecê-las!</p>
 </div>
 
 <div class='bgimg-3'>
 <div class='caption'>
 <span class='border-tres'><a href='#compartilhar' title='Compartilhe o (primeiro) livro do Eterno Inconformado com os coleguinhas!'>Espalhe!</a></span>
 </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class='boxtextop'>
 <p>O (primeiro) Livro do Eterno Inconformado é um material autoral e registrado disponibilizado gratuitamente. É proibida, sem a prévia autorização por escrito do autor, sua reprodução (incluindo quaisquer formas de cópia e/ou distribuição) para fins comerciais e/ou lucrativos. Todavia, é autorizada e incentivada a reprodução e distribuição desta obra, desde que referencie a fonte, não altere o conteúdo original, nem o utilize para fins comerciais como reiterado.
 <p>Para sugestões, críticas, comentários, pedidos de oração ou outro assunto de teu interesse, acesse nosso formulário de contato ou nos envie um e-mail.</p>
 <p>Para contato com o autor, envie um e-mail para: <a href='mailto:macedofagundes@outlook.com'>macedofagundes@outlook.com</a></p>
 </div>
 
 <div class='bgimg-1'>
 <div class='caption'>
 <span class='border-quatro'><a title='Baixe o (primeiro) livro do Eterno Inconformado em PDF' href='https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zuaw2vm1wig1w3m/o-primeiro-livro-do-eterno-inconformado-pdf.pdf?dl=1' target='_blank'>Baixar PDF</a></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Aplicou o `<meta name="viewport" >`??

Comment: Sim, @GuilhermeNascimento. Mas, não funciona. =\

Comment: Como esta o seu `<meta name="viewport">`? Posta ele aqui por favor

Comment: ih cara, efeito paralax em disp. móveis é um problema.... não tenha pretensão desses efeitos funcionarem em desktop e móveis da mesma forma... geralmente em disp. moveis e gente simplifica a coisa ao máximo... efeito paralax em disp. móveis não serve pra muita coisa... quem acessa seu site em disp. moveis quer praticidade e não gastar a franquia de dados. Com dizia o saudoso Marcelo Rezende: "vai vendo"..

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1' name='viewport'/>

Comment: Nem no iPhone funcionou, fica cinza no fundo ao invés da imagem

Comment: Você poderia me mostrar uma captura de como aparece no iPhone, @GuilhermeNascimento ? macedofagundes@outlook.com (Não sei se aqui insere imagens). Obrigado, cara!